# Key in Request Token is null or blank- Brick red Social Auth

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, jakarta-ee, oauth

I need to import contacts to the enable my web app users to send invitation to his/her friends from my site, I am using [SocioAuth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) Open source API to get this done, I have written 2 servlets to get this done I am pasting the code of my servlet. when I deployed the app in my Ec2 instance, I am getting an exception saying "Key in request token is null or blank in the line number 27 of the NewSocialAuthentication,

package com.auth.actions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider;
import org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProviderFactory;

public class NewSocialAuthentication extends HttpServlet{

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Coming to doGet of NewSocialApp..");
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String socialAppId = request.getParameter("id");
    System.out.println("SocialAppId: "+socialAppId);
    AuthProvider provider;
    try {
        provider = AuthProviderFactory.getInstance(socialAppId);
        String returnToUrl = "http://ec2-50-19-118-108.compute-1.amazonaws.com/SocialAuthNew6/return";
        System.out.println("Return URL..." + returnToUrl);
        String urlString = provider.getLoginRedirectURL(returnToUrl);
        System.out.println("URLString: "+urlString);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("SocialAuth", provider);
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(urlString));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
package com.auth.actions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider;
import org.brickred.socialauth.Contact;
import org.brickred.socialauth.Profile;
import org.brickred.socialauth.util.*;

public class ReturnServlet extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Coming to doGet of Return Servlet..");
        try{
            AuthProvider provider = (AuthProvider)request.getSession().getAttribute("SocialAuth");//this the line is rising exception 
            Profile p = provider.verifyResponse(request);
            System.out.println(p.getFirstName());
            List<Contact> contactsList = provider.getContactList();
            for(int i=0;i<contactsList.size();i++){
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                System.out.println(contactsList.get(i).getFirstName()+" : "+contactsList.get(i).getLastName());
                out.println(contactsList.get(i).getFirstName());
                out.println(contactsList.get(i).getLastName());

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Kaustubh P Yes I found the solutions

Comment: Could you tell us what you did to get a solution?

Comment: @Kaustubh P I have posted the code here kindly have a look and if u have any doubts or issues regarding this kindly let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is the servlet which redirects to the email service provider

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider;
import org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProviderFactory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class NewSocialAuthentication
 */
public class NewSocialAuthentication extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public NewSocialAuthentication() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String socialAppId = request.getParameter("id");
    System.out.println("SocialAppId: "+socialAppId);
    AuthProvider provider;
    try {
        provider = AuthProviderFactory.getInstance(socialAppId);
        //String returnToUrl = "http://ec2-50-16-183-101.compute-1.amazonaws.com/SocialAuthNew/return";

        String returnToUrl = "u r returning url ";

        System.out.println("Return URL..." + returnToUrl);
        String urlString = provider.getLoginRedirectURL(returnToUrl);
        System.out.println("URLString: "+urlString);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("SocialAuth", provider);
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(urlString));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

the return url would look like this I have embedded in the jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider" %>
<%@page import="org.brickred.socialauth.Contact" %>
<%@page import="org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider" %>
<%@page import="org.brickred.socialauth.Profile" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>




Insert title here

## CONTACT LIST

<%
try{
    AuthProvider provider = (AuthProvider)request.getSession().getAttribute("SocialAuth");
    try{
        System.out.println(provider.getContactList());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Encountered..");
    }
    Profile p = provider.verifyResponse(request);
    List contactsList = provider.getContactList();
%>

Hello, <%= p.getFirstName() %>

Contact List

First Name
      Email
<%
    for(int i=0;i
      "/><%= contactsList.get(i).getFirstName() %><%= contactsList.get(i).getEmail() %>
      
    <%
    }
     %>

```
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="GET CONTACTS"/>
 </form>
```

<%
 }
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>